# Program that converts a number to a letter of the alphabet - follow-up

Tags: c, converting

This is a follow up from my previous post: [Program that converts a number to a letter of the alphabet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/214512/194141)

This is meant to teach my little brother (who only knows how to make games in *Geometry Dash*) about C, and computers. This is an example I've written meant to be shown and explained to him.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  //A string is an array of characters
  const char * alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWSYZ";
  int temp,    letter   = 0;

  while( (1 <= letter && letter <= 26) == false){
    /* 
     * if scanf fails, valadate input to avoid infinite loop 
     * (the below while statement). 
     * Uncomment the below printf and comment out the below 
     * while statement to see what happens if you type 
     * something like "asdef4grvgrthd" instead of a number.
     */
    if(scanf("%d", &letter) != 1){
      while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
      //printf("Fun loop :) ");
    }
  }

  printf("The number %i corresponds to the letter '%c'\n", 
          letter, alphabet[letter-1]);
}
```

This is intended to help beginners understand C by being a slightly harder "Hello World" program.

Comment: C & C++ are two very different languages.  Which is this supposed to be?  It has aspects of both.  Specifically, which compiler are you using.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I tagged it in C++ as it works in both C && C++, although since this is supposed to be an example in C I've removed the C++ tag.

Comment: `sizeof(alphabet) == 27`, there's a trailing null character in there. `strlen(alphabet) == 26`.

Comment: Hi I have rolled back quite a few of your edits. It is important on this site to preserve valid answers and we ask that you not update your code to include feedback. Please see [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/162379) for more information on how you can share your improvements with the community.

Answer (score 19):

- `int letter` is not a letter. When printing you call it `The number`. Name it accordingly: `int number`.
- The condition `(1 <= letter && letter <= 26) == false` is very hard to follow. As a general rule, avoid boolean constants in conditions. Rewriting it as:

  ```
  !(1 <= letter && letter <= 26)
  ```

  immediately calls for a deMorgan transformation into a much more readable form:

  ```
  (letter < 1 || letter > 26)
  ```

  It is also recommended to not rely on the operator precedence, which is very easy to get wrong. Use parenthesis instead:

  ```
  ((letter < 1) || (letter > 26))
  ```
- Avoid raw loops. Each loop represent an important algorithm, and as such deserves a name. The goal of:

  ```
  while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
  ```

  is to discard the line. Factor it out into a function:

  ```
  void discard_line()
  {
      int temp;
      while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n') {
      }
  }
  ```

  As a perk benefit, `temp` is no longer cluttering the essential logic.

  I also recommend to be a bit more explicit with the empty loops.
- Avoid magic numbers. `26` is really `strlen(alphabet)`. Better yet, declare the alphabet as an array, rather than a pointer, and use `sizeof`.

Comment: Is "((letter < 1) || (letter > 26)" suppose to be "((letter < 1) || (letter > 26))" (extra parentheses messing)?

Comment: @AlexAngel Of course, thanks for noticing.

Comment: The pattern `min <= x && x <= max` is pretty standard for a _between_ test. I'd rather keep it that way instead of tearing the both `number` expressions apart.

Comment: You make good points -- renaming "letter" to number && declaring "alphabet" as an array. I'll edit the example.

Comment: Your de Morgan transformation is terrible.  At least make it `letter < 1 || 26 < letter` (but I still prefer the "inside" formatting).  I also find the additional parens make the code much less readable.

Comment: I think `((letter < 1) || (letter > 26))` is the most readable form. You're reading it straight `if letter < 1 or letter > 26`. OP's `(1 <= letter && letter <= 26) == false` was one of the most confusing ifs I've seen for looong time

Answer (score 13):

Bug: When you feed an empty file to your program, it ends up in an endless loop.

Bug: the 24th letter of the English alphabet is X, not S.

Instead of `const char *` you should rather declare `const char alphabet[]`, to make the code match the comment above it. Don't confuse strings and pointers to strings. The [authors of the cs50 library do that](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/163), and they do much damage to the thousands of students who trust in them.

Comment: Changed the extra 'S' to an 'X' and changed the variable "alphabet" to an array. I don't know how to fix the empty file bug.

Comment: @AlexAngel check for empty at the start and return null or 0.

Answer (score 2):

1. Never forget the trailing nul.  `sizeof(alphabet)` is 27, not 26.
2. Don't use `== false`.  It is too close to `== true`, which almost never works, especially in C.  Use prefix operator `!` instead.  Then, as others suggest, consider reducing with de Morgan's laws, or maybe not.
3. `(EOF & '\n' & '\r')` evaluates to `8` (usually).  This is not a set operation.
4. Consider using a `do { ... } while (condition)` loop.

Comment: 1) Fixed by changing "<= sizeof()" to "< sizeof()"

Comment: 2) Since most people are suggesting it I've made this change

Comment: 3) EOF (26) & '\n' (10) & '\r' (13) does equal 8, why is it not a set operation?

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 don't correspond to any of the code in the question.  Are you sure that this is a review?

Comment: @TobySpeight: OP has been updating the source.

Comment: @AlexAngel: Well, it looked like you were trying to write that the value on the left was not any of three values on the right.  This entry on the right, in mathematics, is called a set.  C doesn't have these.  The test could be done with a switch, or with the now present temporary variable.  Also, EOF (as a C constant, provided by stdio.h) is not 26, it is (usually) -1.

Comment: @DavidG.: Would the following work better?:
```for(int temp, b=true;b;temp=getchar()){
      switch(temp){case EOF:case'\n':case'\r':b=false;break;}
}```

Comment: @Alex No, it won't work better. Instead of the complicated `for` loops, you should better use `while` loops until you understand them better. The `for` loop you wrote accesses an uninitialized variable, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlexAngel: I think the best your going to get in this case calls for a goto, or a function.  `for (;;) { switch (getchar()) { case EOF:case'\n':case'\r':goto after_loop;}}after_loop:;`  The function version would use return instead of goto.  The function solution is probably better. An even better solution might be to have read a full line with fgets() and parsed it with sscanf() or strtol() or atoi().

Answer (score 2):

Robust input is difficult to get right in C!

The input loop is broken when we reach end of file: it will loop indefinitely.  What we want to do is to give up completely when we get `EOF` back from `scanf()`:

```
  int items = scanf("%d", &letter);
  if (items == EOF) {
      fputs("Failed to read input\n", stderr);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if (items != 1) {
      /* skip the rest of this line, discarding the return value
         (we'll deal with errors next time round the loop). */
      scanf("%*[^\n]");
      continue;
  }
```

(We'll need to include `<stdlib.h>` for a definition of `EXIT_FAILURE`.)

---

The alphabetic characters can be declared `static` rather than `auto`.  Although `main()` is only executed once in this program, the `static` declaration can help your compiler avoid unnecessary code.

---

The declaration of `main()` should be a prototype - explicitly show it takes no arguments by writing `(void)`.

---

## Modified program

This includes some observations mentioned in other reviews; I won't repeat them here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static const int length = sizeof alphabet - 1; /* don't count the NUL */

    int letter = 0;
    do {
        int items = scanf("%d", &letter);
        if (items == EOF) {
            fputs("Failed to read input\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (items != 1) {
            /* skip the rest of this line, discarding the return value
               (we'll deal with errors next time round the loop). */
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            continue;
        }
    } while (letter < 1 || letter > length);

    printf("The number %i corresponds to the letter '%c'\n",
           letter, alphabet[letter-1]);
}
```

Comment: 1.  You don't need to initialize letter because it is always initialized by scanf.  2.  I would write the trailing `while` test as `while (letter < 1 || length < letter)` (it's much easier to read multiple comparisons of a single variable if they are all in the same direction).  3.  I do miss BCPL's `DO ... UNTIL` which would have allowed `until (1 <= letter && letter <= length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither C nor C++ are the friendliest languages to get acquainted with programming, and character I/O is not their forte either. Besides, these raw C arrays/pointers are both an eyesore and a headache.

```
int temp,    letter   = 0;
```

I wouldn't mix uninitialized and initialized variables.
For an educational code, each variable should be on a separate line with a comment defining its role.

This tinkering with EOFs and newlines is painful to watch. Handling errors is certainly a part of a programmer's job, but I would rather start with a program that can be read without prior knowledge of circa 1970 technicalities and introduce the gritty details only later.

I'd rather use `getline()` on `stdin` (letting the runtime handle this messy string allocation and terminators business) and `atoi()` to handle wrong input as simply as possible.
Or possibly use `argc`, `argv` to get rid of the I/O scan altogether, though the notion of command line arguments might not be terribly intuitive either at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

A cardinal rule of good programming is to process return values appropriately.

Specifically, `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a success true/false boolean. Not processing the return value properly (here: `while(!getchar())`) leads to various undesirable effects, including the problem with the endless loop when fed an empty file.

Additionally, as numerous others have already pointed out,
`while( !(1 <= number && number < sizeof(alphabet)) )` is begging to be rewritten (not just for clarity, but for efficiency as well!) as `while ((letter < 1) || (letter > sizeof(alphabet)))`

And since you do not need to validate 'number' until after the number has been read.
having two `while` loops is unnecessary.

If you combine (a) check return values, (b) validate inputs properly, you get something like this:

```
int number = 0;
while (1) {
     int c = getchar(); /* get something from stdin */
     if (c == EOF || c == '\r' || c == '\n') 
        break;  /* input completed */
     if (c < '0' || c > '9') 
        break; /* invalid input - treat as input completed */
     number = (number * 10) + (c - '0');
     if (number > 99) /* overflow? (more than two digits?) */ 
         number = 100; /* limit the overflow, but remember it */
}
if (number >= 1 && number < sizeof(alphabet))
    printf("The number %i corresponds to the letter '%c'\n", 
          number, alphabet[number-1]);
```

Comment: Be careful - in the code posted `alphabet` is a pointer, so `sizeof alphabet` has no relation to the string length!

Comment: @user5438932: From what I can follow you check if the `character` == `'EOF'`, `'\r'`, or `'\n'` --> if `True` check if the number is in the bounds of the `alphabet` length; else check if `character` is numeric --> if `True` then check in bounds; from there I can't tell what is happening or why the line `number = (number * 10) + (c - '0');` and below is needed.